# How to avoid having only one class during cross-validation

Tags: logistic, cross-validation, binary-data, unbalanced-classes

I have to perform a binary classification. My dataset is quite small 280 samples and quite imbalanced (1:10 ratio). I kept around 100 sample as testing and about 140 for training.
My input variables are about 100 and are stationary time series.

I would like to use GridSearchCV together with L1-Logistic classifier to perform feature selection with roc_auc as a score, but first I just want to check how the cv_score is with a default L1-Logistic classifier, as follows,

```
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=42) #default settings
kfold= model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2) #split the data, specific for time series

train_cv = cross_val_score(X=X_train,y=np.ravel(y_train),estimator=clf,cv=kfold)
print("TRAIN GROUP")
print("\nCross-validation accuracy scores:",train_cv)
print("Mean score:",train_cv.mean())

# Now predict on the test group
print("\nTEST GROUP")
y_pred = clf.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train)).predict(X_test)
y_pred_prob = clf.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train)).predict_proba(X_test)
print("\nAccuracy score:", accuracy_score(y_test.values, y_pred))
print("\nROC_AUC score:",roc_auc_score(y_test.values, y_pred_prob[:,1]))
```

the result is the following,

```
C:\Users\luigi.simeone\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:548: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\luigi.simeone\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 531, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\luigi.simeone\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py", line 1372, in fit
    raise ValueError("This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes"
ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 0
```

the error is clear, during one of the 2 splits, the training set only had one class the 0 one as demonstrated here (blue is train, orange is validation),

[image]

Now, I guess this is due to the fact that the dataset is imbalanced and not so large but I do not know how to solve it.

Can anybody help me to get around this problem?
I had an idea, maybe stupid one, what if I convert the first sample from 0 to 1, in order to have at least one sample of the class 1 in the first split, and after I penalise somehow that sample?
But I would not really know how to penalise it.

Comment: This strikes me as a programming problem, not a statistical one.

Comment: Flipping the class of the first sample is explicitly learning the wrong thing.  If you have no positive cases in the first 50 examples, then you cannot learn a classification from them alone.  I'm not sure what to suggest other than to ensure that any splits you make include at least a couple of the first positive cases in the training set.

Comment: Hi Ben, yes, you are right, that is why I thought of penalising such sample afterwards. Another option would be not to pass cv=kfold, but instead a "manual splitting". I noticed that the training set contains two regions of 1s, therefore I could manually find an index to split these two regions. Looking at above I could say up to 100 is training and after is validation. However, how can I pass such split to cross_val_score?